# comparison of two series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a convergent series of the form $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n^{2}}$, where $a_{n}\in\mathbb{C}$, is it possible that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n(n-1)}$  diverge? I can't find a sequence $a_{n}$ such that the latter series diverge while another converge. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not using comparison test (limit case)?

Comment: Comparsion test shows the former sequence less than latter sequence, which tells nothing about if the latter sequence converge or diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to see that, for every $n\geq2$, we have, for example, $$\frac{n}{n-1}<3$$ hence $$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left|a_{n}\right|^{2}}{n\left(n-1\right)}<\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left|a_{n}\right|^{2}}{n^{2}}$$ so the answer is no.